# SSL Certificate Is Not Installing Properly in IIS 8

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to install `.cer` format SSL Certificate in **Windows Server 2012** and **IIS 8** using the **Complete Certificate Request** wizard.

After that, the certificate cannot find under the server certificates and cannot bind with any sites. It is not available under certificates in root console using `mmc`. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem recently, it was due to the fact that i didn't import the CA certificates first (signer) in the Windows Certs (and in IIS it was disappearing right after the import, as i suppose it couldn't trust it)

import the certificate of your CA in the trusted root certificates, and intermediate certificates first, and then your import will work